# Nested XML Example?

Tags: iphone, xml

I'm currently using XML to read some data into my iPhone app and it isn't going very well. My iPhone app is able to read XML well, but it seems like my XML is a little off and I'm not exactly sure why.

It is possible to do something like this at all?

```
<events>
<name>First Event's Name</name>
<date>First Event's Date</date>
<description>First Event's Description</description>
</events>

<events>
<name>Second Event's Name</name>
<date>Second Event's Date</date>
<description>Second Event's Description</description>
</events>
```

I've cross-checked with another XML file to be sure that my parsing of XML is working. I searched high and low for some examples (even looked at some XML source codes) on this, but my app refuses to read anything after the first  tags...

Comment: Is that your entire XML file? I don't fully understand what problem you're having, but it sounds like maybe you don't have a root element containing the above example. Surround your example with another tag, maybe `<events>` and use `<event>` for each one instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a structure more like this:

```
<events>
    <event>
        <name>First Event's Name</name>
        <date>First Event's Date</date>
        <description>First Event's Description</description>
    </event>
    <events>
        <name>Second Event's Name</name>
        <date>Second Event's Date</date>
        <description>Second Event's Description</description>
    </event>
</events>
```

Note that you can only have one "top-level" node - in this case `events`

Comment: I'll give that a try real quick!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm a complete noob when it comes to XML and your explanation (and example) helped me a lot. Thanks again!